# MVC 5 - can not get globalisation running

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-validation, jquery-globalize, javascript-globalize

I want to add globalization because the site asks the user for a date. And my german user want to type "31.12.1966" and not "1966-12-31".

So I add the nuget-Packages
"jQuery.Validation.Globalize" and
"jquery-globalize"
to the project.

Now I am not able to configure my BundleConfig! From my research I know, that I Need globalize.js and some other files. So I try to make a bündle:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/global").Include(
           "~/Scripts/globalize.js",
           "~/Scripts/cldr.js").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/cldr/",
           "~/Scripts/globalize/")
           );
```

The using in the view:

```
...
@section Scripts {

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/global")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/unobtrusiveajax") 


<script type="text/javascript">


    $(function () {
        $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
            Globalize.culture("de-DE");
            // you can alternatively pass the culture to parseDate instead of
            // setting the culture above, like so:
            // parseDate(value, null, "en-AU")
            return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value) !== null;
        }
    });
</script>
}
```

But I get an error:

```
Error at line 9, column 5 in http://localhost:58289/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js
0x800a138f - runtimeerror in JavaScript: 
The property "methods" of a undefindes or null-pointer can not bei called
```

I translated the message from this german original:

```
Ausnahmefehler in Zeile 9, Spalte 5 in http://localhost:58289/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js
0x800a138f - Laufzeitfehler in JavaScript: 
Die Eigenschaft "methods" eines undefinierten oder Nullverweises kann nicht abgerufen werden.
```

Need I more/other files in the bundle?

What can I do? Any help?

Sincerly
Peter

Comment: Can you try Globalize 1.x (the new version)?

Comment: I use Glabalize 1.2.2

Comment: On Globalize 1.x, there's no `Globalize.culture`. I'm afraid you're using 0.x API with the new 1.x lib

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:

In my view is the following script block:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/unresolved.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/currency.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/date.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/plural.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/relative-time.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/unit.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Use $.getJSON instead of $.get if your server is not configured to return the
        // right MIME type for .json files.
        $.when(
            $.get("/Scripts/cldr/main/de/ca-gregorian.json"),
            $.get("/Scripts/cldr/main/de/numbers.json"),
            $.get("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
            $.get("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/timeData.json"),
            $.get("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/weekData.json")
        ).then(function () {
            // Normalize $.get results, we only need the JSON, not the request statuses.
            return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
                return result[0];
            });
        }).then(Globalize.load)
    .then(function () {
        Globalize.locale("de-DE");
    });
    });
```

My data-class has an annotiation like this:

```
...
[Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Geburtsdatum { get; set; }
...
```

And - very important!! - you must get the data-files!
This is nessecary because the clrd-data is **not** part of the NuGet-Packages "jQuery.Validation.Globalize" / "jquery-globalize".
(Yes, it is mentioned on the Project-page - but I didn't see it... :-( )

I installed Bower (per NuGet) and installed then via Bower the Cldr-data. Example:

```
 bower install cldr-dates-full
```

(see overview over packages and install instruction [1](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-json))

Then I moved the needed json-files (here you find an online-tool for file-selection [2](http://johnnyreilly.github.io/globalize-so-what-cha-want/#/?currency=true&date=true&message=true&number=true&plural=true&relativeTime=true&unit=true)) from Directory "bower_components" to "scripts\cldr\main\de" respectively "scripts\cldr\supplemental".

I add them to the project and mark them as "Content", "no copy".

So finally it works!!! :-)

If I manage it to bundle the js- and json-files, I will update the answer.

Comment: Did you have any success bundling the json files? (js- files should not be a problem, shouldn't they?)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't manage it. The problem is the order of the files. I don't wont to write my own bundlehandler and the default order them by alphabet. And this is not working!

Comment: I found the globalize-compiler - it does the bundling pretty well. It was not that easy to get it running though.