# MVC 5, globalize, validate german date: How to bundle the js-scripts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification, jquery-globalize

In the answer to this question ([MVC 5 - can not get globalisation running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763260/mvc-5-can-not-get-globalisation-running)) I solve the problem with a bunch of "<sript src="..." declarations and some js.

What I not managed: I want to bundle the scripts. If I try it like this (excerpt from bundleConfig.cs):

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryvalDe").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                    "~/Scripts/cldr.js",
                        "~/Scripts/cldr/event.js",
                        "~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js",
                        "~/Scripts/cldr/unresolved.js",
                        "~/Scripts/globalize.js",
                        "~/Scripts/globalize/currency.js",
                        "~/Scripts/globalize/number.js",
                        "~/Scripts/globalize/date.js",
                        "~/Scripts/globalize/plural.js",
                        "~/Scripts/globalize/relative-time.js",
                        "~/Scripts/globalize/unit.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"
                    ));
```

But I get an error from JavaScript: "Globalize" is undefined

It seems, the order of scrpts is changed...

At the moment I use a Workaround: I wrote an custom HTM-Helper.

```
 public static class GermanDateValidationExtension
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ScriptsForGermanDateValidation(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString("<script src=\"~/ Scripts / jquery.validate.js\"></script>\n" +
                                 "<script src = \"~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js\"></script>\n" +
                                 "<script src = \"~/Scripts/cldr.js\"></script>\n" +
                                 "<script src = \"~/Scripts/cldr/event.js\"></ script>\n" +
                                 "<script src = \"~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js\"></script>\n" +
                                 "<script src = \"~/Scripts/cldr/unresolved.js\"></script>\n" +
                                 "<script src = \"~/Scripts/globalize.js\"></script>\n" +
                                 "<script src = \"~/Scripts/globalize/currency.js\" ></script>\n" +
                                 "<script src = \"~/Scripts/globalize/number.js\"></script>\n" +
                                 "<script src = \"~/Scripts/globalize/date.js\"></script>\n" +
                                 "<script src = \"~/Scripts/globalize/plural.js\" ></script>\n" +
                                 "<script src = \"~/Scripts/globalize/relative-time.js\"></script>\n" +
                                 "<script src = \"~/Scripts/globalize/unit.js\"></script>\n" +
                                 "<script src = \"~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js\"></script>\n" +
                                 "<script>\n" +
                                 "$.when(\n" +
                                 "$.get(\"/Scripts/cldr/main/de/ca-gregorian.json\"),\n" +
                                 "$.get(\"/Scripts/cldr/main/de/numbers.json\"),\n" +
                                 "$.get(\"/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json\"),\n" +
                                 "$.get(\"/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/timeData.json\"),\n" +
                                 "$.get(\"/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/weekData.json\")\n" +
                                 ").then(function() {\n" +
                                 "return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function(result) {\n" +
                                 "return result[0];\n" +
                                 "});\n" +
                                 "}).then(Globalize.load)\n" +
                                 ".then(function() {\n" +
                                 "Globalize.locale(\"de-DE\");\n" +
                                 "});\n" +
                                 "</ script > ");
    }

}
```

And use it in the view:

```
...
@section Scripts {      
@Html.ScriptsForGermanDateValidation()
}  
...
```

My question is: How to bundle the scripts correctly?

Comment: Try using a class which implements `IBundleOrderer` (e.g. `class BundleReorder : IBundleOrderer { ... }`, place `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` or `IEnumerable<BundleFile>` method on it & then set in BundleConfig: `bundle.Orderer = new BundleReorder();`. Check for some info: https://stevescodingblog.co.uk/changing-the-ordering-for-single-bundles-in-asp-net-4/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems originated from bundling order which rendered `jquery.validate.globalize.js` before `globalize.js`, which uses "dependency tree" established in favor of well-known libraries & their custom extensions will rendered before others. Hence, in order to set load order as you want, create a class which implements `IBundleOrder` interface & its corresponding extension method:

```
// from Sebastián Rojas (/a/26602075)
class UnorderedBundleOrderer : IBundleOrderer
{
    public IEnumerable<BundleFile> OrderFiles(BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files)
    {
        return files;
    }
}

static class BundleExtensions
{
    public static Bundle UnorderedBundling(this Bundle bundle)
    {
        bundle.Orderer = new UnorderedBundleOrderer();
        return bundle;
    }
}
```

Then you can use custom bundling order above in BundleConfig.cs file:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryvalDe")
           .UnorderedBundling()
           .Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
            ...
            ...
            "~/Scripts/globalize.js",
            ...
            ...
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"
    ));
}
```

Related issue:

[ASP.NET MVC - Bundle Config order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323409/asp-net-mvc-bundle-config-order)

[Ordering of Files within a bundle - What are the known libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325487/ordering-of-files-within-a-bundle-what-are-the-known-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is - how Tetsuya Yamamoto says: Write your own orderer.

```
public IEnumerable<BundleFile> OrderFiles(BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files)
    {
        return files;
    }
```

and use it:

```
 var qvDeBundle  =new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryvalDe").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                    "~/Scripts/cldr.js",
                        "~/Scripts/cldr/event.js",
                        "~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js",
                        "~/Scripts/cldr/unresolved.js",
                        "~/Scripts/globalize.js",
                        "~/Scripts/globalize/currency.js",
                        "~/Scripts/globalize/number.js",
                        "~/Scripts/globalize/date.js",
                        "~/Scripts/globalize/plural.js",
                        "~/Scripts/globalize/relative-time.js",
                        "~/Scripts/globalize/unit.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"
                    );         
        qvDeBundle.Orderer=new UnorderBundleOrderer();
        bundles.Add(qvDeBundle);
```