# MVc 5 - validation german date with unobtrusiv js - a simple approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, javascript-globalize

The question: How get the unobtrusiv validation of a german date running in MVC?

Because I can't find a running example of using globalize 1.x with MVC 5 to validate a german date I needed two days to get it running.

The problems are the order of the js-files, getting the cldr-data and putting it all together in an way it can be reused.

In the answer I will show my current solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this zip-file (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/75dx6alck7itwia/AABFkcgOQVc1bUXFE_jYfR_da?dl=0) you find all files you need.

It includes

- an short todo.txt (de and en)
- the cldr-data (jsons) in sub-directories
- a custom HTML-Helper-class wich writes the needed HTML/js-Scripts to the view.

It seems, that rendering by the helper not allways works. So if there are problems with that, copy the code to every (edit / new) view.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/unresolved.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/currency.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/date.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/plural.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/relative-time.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/unit.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>        

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Use $.getJSON instead of $.get if your server is not configured to return the
        // right MIME type for .json files.
        $.when(
            $.get("/Scripts/cldr/main/de/ca-gregorian.json"),
            $.get("/Scripts/cldr/main/de/numbers.json"),
            $.get("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
            $.get("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/timeData.json"),
            $.get("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/weekData.json")
        ).then(function () {
            // Normalize $.get results, we only need the JSON, not the request statuses.
            return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
                return result[0];
            });
        }).then(Globalize.load)
    .then(function () {
        Globalize.locale("de-DE");
    });
    });
</script>
```

I hope it helps.

This solution based on the answer to [MVC 5 - can not get globalisation running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763260/mvc-5-can-not-get-globalisation-running).
If you want to use a bündle, see [MVC 5, globalize, validate german date: How to bundle the js-scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920572/mvc-5-globalize-validate-german-date-how-to-bundle-the-js-scripts)